# Populating a Hashmap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Ok I am having quite a bit of an issue. I want to populate my hash map with a set of String keywords. So basically, The user enters a keyword and if it matches the keyword in the hash map a parseFile method is called. Else if the user input is a synonym  of the keyword, I search the hash map for the original keyword. But my issue is populating the hash map. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    /* your synonym map of keywords and you have to populate 
    it before the user can give values.*/ 
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    populateSynonymMap(); //populate the map


    /*Get user response*/ 
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");
    System.out.print("> ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    /*first check if the input already is the original one*/
    if (synonymMap.containsKey(input)) {
        parseFile(input);
    } else {
        /*if not then search the synonymMap to get the original keyword*/
        for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {

            String[] value = entry.getValue();                
            if (Arrays.asList(value).contains(input)) {
                parseFile(entry.getKey());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What's your current implementation of that method and why is it failing?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime exception? If so, what is the exact message?

Comment: What is your issue? "populating the hash map" is broad, are you looking for [`Map#put(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-)?

Comment: What i mean by populate is adding values into the map and then searching through those values

Comment: You're using your map backwards. The keys should be the synonyms, the values should be the real keywords.

Comment: If your map is of method scope, shouldn't your populate method return some Map? So you can assign back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can try the following code. This does what you like to accomplish. But I think you need to think of redesigning the way you are looking up keyword synonym.

And if you are facing issues only populating the hashmap it may be because you are defining map inside main method and then not populating it really anywhere else.

So for the second option, you can change assignment in main method like ..

```
    synonymMap = populateSynonymMap(); // populate the map
```

And the sample method to populate the map.

```
private static HashMap<String, String[]> populateSynonymMap() {
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    String s[] = new String[] { "x1", "x2", "x3" };
    String t[] = new String[] { "y1", "y2", "y3" };
    String u[] = new String[] { "z1", "z2", "z3" };

    synonymMap.put("x", s);
    synonymMap.put("y", t);
    synonymMap.put("z", u);

    return synonymMap;

}
```

Comment: @Jordi, I agree. removed the repeated code piece. I now feel it actually gives pointed answer. I request you re consider the downvote please

Answer (score 0):

You must define a method accepting a `Map` to populate

```
public void populateSynonymMap(Map<String, String[]> synonymsMap)
```

or declare your `Map` as attribute in the class to be visible in the method.

Then inside method you must have a word and synonyms array:

```
String word = "synonym";
String[] synonyms = "equivalent,methonim".split(",");
```

Then put both in the map:

```
synonimsMap.put(word, synonyms);
```

Do it as many times as you need (if a lot, define 2 arrays, one `String[]` for words and another `String[][]` for synonims and iterate over them to populate the map in an easier way...

```
String[] words = // populate word array
String[][] synonims = // populate synonims 2d array

for (int c = 0; c < words.length; c++) {
    synonimsMap.put(words[c], synonyms[c]);
}
```

Hope this guides you enough...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than declaring you HashMap as

```
HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
```

Why don't you declare is as

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

& then `arrayListObj.add(entry.getValue());`

then it will obviate the need for this `Arrays.asList(value)`

Initialize the method like

```
public void populateSynonymMap(String key, List<String> value){
    synonymMap.put(key, value);
    }
```

Input values in the List

```
List<String> listOne=new ArrayList<String>();
listOne.add("Input String"); //Keep on adding the Strings in this way
//then call the populateSynonymMap method
//Say your key is A
populateSynonymMap("A", listOne);
```

Comment: Or better, it should be `Map<String,Set<String>>`, with the `Set` indicating that there should be no duplication in your synonyms.